# Can I add white primer to danish oil to keep birch countertops light color?

Tags: finishing, wood

New birch butcher block counter that I’d like to keep as light as possible. I’m thinking of whitewash with diluted primer, oil or water base, and either danish oil top coat or a wipe on poly. Can I add oil primer to the danish oil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I add white primer to danish oil to keep birch countertops light color?

Short answer: yes.

What you'll make is essentially very similar to some commercial products intended for the same purpose, which are essentially one of their existing finishes with some white pigment added<sup>1</sup>.

Longer answer: some experimentation would be *highly* advisable, even if you have experience in painting and other finishing already you won't be able to predict how much whiteness a given quantity of white primer (or paint) will impart to the "Danish oil". So you'll have to do some small tests of various mixes, noting the ratios; *write them down*<sup>2</sup>. Apply the planned number of coats for every mix and assess how the wood looks after they've dried (there is likely to be some change in appearance from wet to dry).

You can use the underside for this testing if you don't have any offcuts to work with. But be sure to protect the top from dings and dents by putting old sheets or a blanket etc. under it while you're working on the back.

> I’m thinking of whitewash with diluted primer, oil or water base, and either danish oil top coat or a wipe on poly.

This is definitely also a viable option; you wouldn't be the first to go this route. Probably obvious but again testing will be necessary to work out how much to thin, how to apply it effectively on such a large surface, how much you need to wipe away excess and possibly other things.

**Note:** if you do it this way and you want to keep the wood as pale as possible it would be advisable to use a waterbased finish (even if you choose to use an oil-based white paint or primer) so that the topcoat doesn't impart a noticeable yellow tinge (which *will* deepen over time, guaranteed).

Choose your waterbased finish with care as they are very much not all equal and you'll want to pick one of the better ones for a countertop.

---

<sup>1</sup> Examples include Skagerak Cura Oil White, Guardian White-pigmented Oil, Rubio Monocoat Oil Plus 2C White 5%, Osmo 3068 Top Oil Natural.

<sup>2</sup> If you have a good memory it's tempting to just rely on it, but you never know if you'll need to repeat this mixture sometime down the road when you can't be certain you'll still remember exact quantities.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I usually don’t have this issue but I really don’t want to mess up the hard work of my contractor/ husband.  I am keep record of all variations of stain and top coat.  One has to be workable!  Ps osmo polyx white satin sounded good but at this point too much of an unknown.

Comment: FWIW if you wanted to go with a commercial product I would suggest Rubio, because recently people have reported irregular performance from Osmo products (I don't pay enough attention to Osmo-related stuff so I don't know which ones, or if it's across the entire range). Rubio Monocoat — even if many users say it really can do with more than just the one coat the name suggests hehe — seems to have a more uniformly good rep and the results of third-party test of water resistance is impressive to say the least.

Comment: So this is what I did and maybe you can help again. . (No speciality woodwork shops in my area or time to order online)
I used Varathane white semi transparent gel stain 1/3 cup, added a 1 Tbl spoon of Minwax Sunbleach oil stain and got the color and texture I liked. I applied with a nylon scrub pad and rubbed it in smoothly.  NOW I need to top coat but I don’t want it to yellow as I’m afraid might happen with an oil base. Can I let dry for a few days and use a good low luster water base poly or is there another route. I have time now to order online if necessary.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you can use a waterbased finish over preceding oil-based stuff once the preceding stuff has had a chance to dry enough. There's no real guideline for how long this will take because there are so many variables that affect drying rates, and a custom mixture is a complete unknown. Obviously the longer you can wait the better, and a week or longer would not hurt. If after a good wait you found the waterbased product is beading too much you can use shellac as an intermediary, but that's not a good buy for you if you don't have a future need. So instead very lightly scuff the surface.

Comment: BTW any oil-based topcoat will absolutely yellow over time (*ambering* to be more precise, because it isn't towards *yellow* yellow) and while many people are resistant to this on paper, to be honest it happens so slowly normally that those living with it generally get used to the incremental change. But that aside they would noticeably add to the yellowness straight away since some kind of yellow, light tan or amber is the native colour of all oil finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding light-colored pigment to the wood, you might want to think about lightening the color of the wood by removing some of the color that's already there (or which develops over time) by bleaching the wood. Here's [a short Bob Vila article](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/bleaching-wood/) about using chlorine bleach, peroxide, and oxalic acid (not at the same time!), and a [This Old House article](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/kitchens/21017444/restoring-a-butcher-block-countertop) about restoring butcher block countertops.

Comment: Caleb thanks for sounding in but this is a new unfinished birch butch block that need to be finished to keep it a nice warm light color and top coated.

Comment: For what it's worth, bleaching back is known not to be permanent in many cases. Obviously birch is already pretty light so a good candidate for not going too dark naturally to begin with, but FFR on woods that are darker (anything beyond oak) unless you bleach to nearly white you can't trust the results long-term, and bleaching like this can only be done using one of the A+B bleaches.